# C++ Trick to avoid pointer comparison

Tags: c++, pointers, equality

I am moving a code base from one programming style to another.

We have a type called `Operand` defined like:

```
class Operand
{...};
```

Then we had

```
class OperandFactory
{
  public:
    const Operand *make_operand (...);
};
```

`OperandFactory` used to hash the `Operand` and keep it in a table. Therefore if you called `make_operand` with the same arguments, you would get the same pointer and pointer comparison over `Operand`s proliferated. Now I need to add a feature that will make this infeasible. So, I implement `operator==` in `Operand` and would like to somehow generate at compile time (better) or run time (better than nothing) error if I ever do a pointer comparison on `Operand`s. What's the best way to achieve this?

This is only to be used during this transition stage, so I don't mind if the solution looks like a hack as long as it captures all comparisons in the code base.

Comment: show code or at least a minimal working reduced example of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can overload the address of operator to return a handle and declare the comparison of two handles (without definition). This would lead to a linker error.

```
#include <iostream>

class Op;

class Handle {
    Op *pri_;
public:
    explicit Handle(Op *o) : pri_(o) {}
    Op *operator->() const { return pri_; }
    Op &operator*() const { return *pri_; }
};

 // force compile time errors on comparison operators
bool operator==(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;
bool operator!=(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;
bool operator>=(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;
bool operator<=(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;
bool operator<(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;
bool operator>(const Handle &, const Handle &) = delete;

class Op {
    int foo_;
public:
    explicit Op(int i) : foo_(i) { }
    Handle operator&() { return Handle(this); };
    void touch() const { std::cout << "foobar"; }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Op i{10};
    Op j{20};

    auto c = &j; // works
    c->touch(); // works
    (*c).touch(); // works

    if (&j == &i) {
        /* will not compile */
    }

}
```

**Note**:

You have to fulfill the `random_access_iterator` requirement for `Handle`!

```
Op i{10}
Handle ref = &i;

ref++; ref--; ++ref; --ref; ref = ref + 10; ref = ref - 10; // should all work.
```

Comment: You may use `= delete` (since C++11) to have compiler errors instead of linker errors.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an operator in your `Operand` class won't help : you want to detect comparisons of *pointers* to `Operand`s. Unfortunately, native types operators can't be overloaded, and pointers are of native type. This is not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: you can overload the address of operator to return a handle and declare the comparison of two handles (without definition). This would lead to a linker error.

Comment: Thinking out of the box. You got it.