# Is there a way to disallow pointer comparison in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, equality

I have a (working) code base where I want to add something like an `is_equivalent` member to a class hierarchy. Scattered throughout the code base there are comparisons like

```
if (foo == bar) ...
```

where `foo` and `bar` are ordinary pointers to objects in the class hierarchy. I would like to introduce usage like the following (as a virtual function in the base class):

```
if (foo->is_equivalent(bar)) ...
```

so that the notion of "equality" is relaxed. A concrete geometric example might be a shape hierarchy, where a `Circle` should be considered equivalent to an `Ellipse` with equal major and minor axes (not a perfect analogy).

What I would like to do is have the compiler help me find all the instances where I have done direct pointer comparison. One thought I had was to provide something like an `operator==(const Shape *, const Shape *)` but that isn't even allowed by C++.

Some pointer comparisons might need to stay pointer comparison, but some will need to be changed into a virtual method call. I'll need to look at each one. What approaches are there to identify all these kinds of comparisons? Temporarily breaking either the build or execution is fine. There is pretty good test coverage.

I have read the question [C++ Trick to avoid pointer comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549422/c-trick-to-avoid-pointer-comparison) which is similar, but more limited because the accepted answer assumes the existence of a factory class.

Comment: Do you consider it a viable option to write a custom static analysis tool for this specific purpose and run it on your code base (potentially periodically)? libclang has a pretty complete AST API that - I'd assume - you can use to filter all pointer comparisons.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: That's a viable idea, and might also be interesting to learn about libclang in its own right.

Comment: Your question's example doesn't make that much sense. `if (foo == bar)` is comparing if the object `foo` is the SAME object as `bar` - which is the same as `char *foo = "abc"; char bar[] = "abc"; if (foo == bar)` - which won't be true, because `foo` and `bar` points at different bits of memory. If you compare `if (*foo == *bar)`, then you can definitely do what you wish already in C++ by implementing `operator==`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson It's exactly that Greg wants to avoid (IMO potentially erroneous, misleading) pointer comparisons. I'm sure he's well aware of the difference between an overloaded `==` operator on objects and the `==` operator that compares pointers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The pointers (mostly, right now) point to statically allocated singleton objects. It's just the way it is. Even if I wanted to change everything to `(*foo == *bar)`, I'd still have to locate all those comparisons, which brings us around to the original question again.

Comment: One simple answer is to rename (or change namespace, hide inside another object, etc) the statically allocated singleton objects...

Comment: I don't see what the circle/ellipse discussion is about. As Mats points out, currently a Circle and another Circle are not equivalent, so the existing codebase cannot be using pointer comparison in order to test equivalence. You're talking about making a big semantic change out of nowhere.

Comment: Note that changing the name is a perfectly valid operation if you are changing the semantics of the system.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, I am. The details are not important, but I'm extending the class hierarchy too (by analogy, adding an `Ellipse` class where the hierarchy already had `Circle`). So I need to identify these types of comparisons.

Comment: You could change `foo` to be of class type that overloads `operator->` to access the underlying singleton, and provides `is_equivalent` or (more confusingly) `operator==`

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Simply changing the name of the singleton objects doesn't help identify where some pointer `foo` is compared to another pointer `bar`.

Comment: You know, there are many ways this could have been coded differently. I'm not asking for additional strategies that could have avoided the problem I'm currently having. I'm asking for strategies to help me get *out* of the situation I'm in.

Comment: Ok, so if you have a `MyClass *foo`, then rename `MyClass` to `MyClass2` - whenever it stops compiling because `MyClass` isn't working, rename the variable `foo` to `foo2` and find out where that stops compiling, etc. Or spend a week or so writing an AST analyzer, and debug that... The latter is probably more fun, but also more complex work (and definitely a greater risk of "taking longer than expected").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a custom code analysis tool. Here's a minimal (and rather trivial) example I've built using `libclang`. This filters out every binary operator in the source. By the means of refining this, you could gather all pointer equality comparisons from the AST.

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void printBinOp(CXCursor cursor)
{
    CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cursor);
    CXSourceLocation begin = clang_getRangeStart(range);
    CXSourceLocation end = clang_getRangeEnd(range);
    CXFile file;
    unsigned begin_offset, end_offset, length;

    // retrieve physical location of AST node
    clang_getSpellingLocation(begin, &file, NULL, NULL, &begin_offset);
    clang_getSpellingLocation(end, NULL, NULL, NULL, &end_offset);
    length = end_offset - begin_offset;

    // Open the file, error checking omitted for clarity
    CXString xfname = clang_getFileName(file);
    const char *fname = clang_getCString(xfname);
    FILE *fhndl = fopen(fname, "r");
    clang_disposeString(xfname);

    // Read the source
    char buf[length + 1];
    fseek(fhndl, begin_offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, length, 1, fhndl);
    buf[length] = 0;
    fclose(fhndl);

    // and print it
    printf("Comparison: %s\n", buf);
}

static enum CXChildVisitResult ptrCompVisitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data)
{
    if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_BinaryOperator) {
        printBinOp(cursor);
    }

    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}

int main()
{
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, "foo.cpp", NULL, 0, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

    clang_visitChildren(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(tu), ptrCompVisitor, NULL);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(tu);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);
    return 0;
}
```

The example file I've used was this imaginary C++ source file (named `foo.cpp`):

```
class Foo {
    int foo;
};

class Bar {
    int bar;
}

int main()
{
    void *f = new Foo();
    void *b = new Bar();

    bool alwaystrue_1 = f == f;
    bool alwaystrue_2 = b == b;

    return f == b;
}
```

For which my tool printed this:

```
Comparison: f == f
Comparison: b == b
Comparison: f == b
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great place to start!